# Induction for arithmetic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I have to solve the following problem:

Let $q \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a_{n+1}=qa_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $a_n=a_0q^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My first idea was to use induction but I dont know exactly how to start. Perhaps someone can give me a hint?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: *"My first idea was to use induction ..."* Good! – "*... but I dont know exactly how to start.*" Usually you start by verifying the "base case", which would be the case $n=0$ in your situation.

Comment: So the case $n=0$ is: $a_1=0 \cdot a_0 \Rightarrow a_0=a_0$ which is true?

Comment: Not quite. Your base case to prove is that $a_0 = a_0\cdot q^0$

Comment: ok, that true ($a_0=a_0 \cdot 1=a_0$). So the next step is to proove $a_{n+1}=a_0 \cdot q^{n+1}$?

Comment: Almost. Your next step is to show that $a_n=a_0\cdot q^n \implies a_{n+1}=a_0\cdot q^{n+1}$

Comment: It looks more like a geometric sequence.

Comment: Ok, here is my try:$a_{n+1}=qa_n=q(a_0q^n)=a_0q^{n+1}$